# Rails API - how to enable ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController

Tags: ember.js, rails-api

I'm using Rails API (`5.2.0`) and hit a problem when uploading a file directly from an Ember app by posting to ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create (`/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads` path). I'm getting `404`error. Does it means that the above controller is just not availabe in Rails API-mode app ? If so, how is it possible to include the corresponding module ? Or I'll have to create a custom controller inheriting from `ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController`?

I created `DirectUploadsController` extending `ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController`as follows:

```
class DirectUploadsController < ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

And defined Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :tag_ids, Array
  validates :title, :body, :tag_ids, presence: true

  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

`PostsSerializer` looks like that:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  attributes :id, :title, :body, :tag_ids, :archived, :photo

  def photo
    url_for(object.photo) if object.photo.attached?
  end
end
```

When checking if a photo was attached to the Post, it seems to be OK:

```
2.5.0 :001 > post = Post.first
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Post id: 28, title: "post-1", body: "azertyui", tag_ids: [12], archived: true, created_at: "2018-10-31 15:26:49", updated_at: "2018-10-31 15:26:49"> 
2.5.0 :002 > post.photo.attached?
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 28], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "photo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => true
```

But when trying to display it in the front-end app on `posts/index` page it fails with errors:

```
Started GET "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-31 17:13:20 +0100
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /Users/Serguei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by PostsController#index as JSONAPI
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  ↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8
[active_model_serializers]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 28], ["record_type", "Post"], ["name", "photo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   ↳ app/serializers/post_serializer.rb:7
[active_model_serializers]   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   ↳ app/serializers/post_serializer.rb:7
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi (30.88ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)



ArgumentError (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):

app/serializers/post_serializer.rb:7:in `photo'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

Where should I set those options ?

`:host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`

I created two repos to reproduce the problem:

1. [Rails API app](https://github.com/belgoros/draft-api/tree/add_file_upload)
2. [Ember App](https://github.com/belgoros/draft-app/tree/add_file_upload) (front-end client)

Comment: I updated the both apps. Now I can save/attache an image to  a Post: `post.photo.attached?`  returns `true`, yay ! The problem is to display it on posts/index page. Sure, I defined API host in Ember `environment.js` and set it in `application.js` adapter. Nevertheless, Ember is still trying to hit `lGET http://localhost:4200/rails/active_storage/representations/dXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--50be86904a865aadf1/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsi/canapex.jpg 404 (Not Found)`. It happens when displaying posts list in the template: `<img src={{post.photo}} alt="post photo" class="img-thumbnail" height="32" width="32">`.

Answer (score -2):

I pushed 2 apps to GitHub:

- [Rails API app](https://github.com/belgoros/draft-api)
- [Ember JS app](https://github.com/belgoros/draft-app)

You will have to:

- create `DirectUploadsController`that extends `ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController`
- modify the corresponding model serializer (see my [PostSerializer](https://github.com/belgoros/draft-api/blob/add_file_upload/app/serializers/post_serializer.rb) as example)
- add `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'` to [development.rb](https://github.com/belgoros/draft-api/blob/add_file_upload/config/environments/development.rb) file (update the corresponding values depending on your environment)

That's all. There are no more tunings or special changes on Ember side.

Hope this helps. Any suggestions and remarks are welcome !